# NodeJS - How to run functions everytime end/start of day is reached?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement daily user stats into my app and I'd like to reset these stats at the end/beginning of each day. How could I do this in NodeJS?

Comment: This question has received a negative score and is liable to be put **on hold** because you barely provided any attempt on your question. As a result, it is too broad, and users can find any possible program that can implement daily user stats.

Comment: The question wasn't how to implement daily stats, but how to schedule functions to run at the beginning/end of the day. The question in the title is very clear. It was obviously clear enough for the right answer to be given..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron). This will allow you to run a function in exact time. As example:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('00 00 00 * * *', () => {
  console.log('This will execute on midnight');
}, null, true);
```